# Retag [precompiler] and burninate

Tags: support, status-declined, burninate-request, retag-request

The questions on [precompiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/precompiler) appear to be intended to be tagged [preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preprocessor) instead. The [precompiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/precompiler) tag has no tag wiki/summary and is only tagged on 39 questions. I say retag them to [preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preprocessor) and just get rid of the tag.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not convinced a precompiler is strictly the same as a preprocessor, but maybe that is just an academic distinction and not a practical one.

As most questions tagged [precompiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/precompiler) are also tagged with C/C++ or SASS/CSS where this distinction between precompiler and preprocessor seems relevant, my guts say that burnination of the tag [precompiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/precompiler) should not take place.

Just leave the tag; if anything, clean-up by members that are familiar with the technology stack the question is about would be appropriate.

Comment: I agree about keeping the tag. A pre-compiler is more like something QT uses or the first C++ "compilers": translate additional contructs to the target language. It's basically a mixture of a preprocessor (which has no idea about the target language semantics/context) and a transpiler (which translates from one language to another).

Comment: @Olaf I'm not sure I agree with "which has no idea about the target language semantics" - a preprocessor *must* know the rules of the target language, otherwise what's the point of writing Sass, for example, if it can't compile successfully to CSS?

Comment: @TylerH: I don't know the tool you mentioned. But that might be a precompiler or transpiler actually. Unfortunately the three terms are often used wrongly. See many [tag:precompiler] questions which are about the C **preprocessor** actually. and no, that has no idea bout the semantics, but some of the syntax and grammar (three other confused terms).